# Entity Framework won't set FKs when creating a new record

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework

I am attempting to add a Line to an existing header in the following conceptual model through entity framework.

[image: data model]

I have exposed this model through a wcf data service. I am attempting to add a record like this:

```
SampleModelContainer context = new SampleModelContainer(new Uri("http://localhost:57588/WcfDataService1.svc"));

Line newLine = new Line();
newLine.item = 123;

// Generate new LineId
newLine.LineId = context.Lines.ToList().Last().LineId + 1;

// Grab a random header (doesn't matter right now)
newLine.Header = context.Headers.ToList().First();

context.AddToLines(newLine);            
context.SaveChanges();
```

This fails with an error that states that my HeaderId must not be null. However, shouldn't this be filled in by EF because I set the navigation property? If I fill in the HeaderId, it works, but I don't want to set that every time.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Added connection string

Comment: This question has very poor quality. Tag is mentioning WCF but the question itself doesn't have any single note about how is WCF related to the question. Moreover comment under one answer is mentioning WCF Data Services which gives the problem utterly different scope - I guess you have a problem on the client side, don't you? If you want to get answer first learn how to ask a question and how to use correct tags - we don't see your code so we cannot infer what is going on there! Btw:  `context.Lines.ToList().Last().LineId + 1` I got a heart attack when I saw that.

Comment: @Ladislav I say in the question that my EF model is exposed through a WCF data service. (3rd line) All of the code provided is on my client. What other code would you like to see? I have added very little besides what is auto generated. Also, this is a sample project that is simple enough to expose my issue, in my real database we have a set of number sequence functions that provide a set of alphanumeric primary keys that overly complicate my simple scenario for now. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. I completely missed that part even I read your question 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
newLine.Header = context.Headers.ToList().First();
```

Do this:

```
newLine.HeaderId = context.Headers.First().HeaderId;
```

Don't try to assign objects directly, set the appropriate foreign key (in this case `HeaderId`) and let the framework take care of the rest.

**EDIT**

See BrokenGlass's answer.

Comment: I understand that this works. But isn't the point of EF to make it so that I don't have to deal with FKs? While this is a relatively simple expample, what if the lines also had a collection of items? Then I would have to create the line, get the id of the newly created line, then apply that id out. I thought the point of EF was to allow me to create collections within the objects, then make a single call to create the set?

Comment: @Jared it is because `Line` object is not a proxy. hence there is not logic inside the setter of `Header` property to update the value of `HeaderId`

Comment: @Eranga that makes sense, but I still need to figure out the correct way to create these objects without setting the FK. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work given your entity data model:

```
Line newLine = new Line();
newLine.Item = 123;

// Grab a random header (doesn't matter right now)
var header = context.Headers.First();
newLine.Header = header; // Establish the relationship

// Add the new line
context.Lines.AddObject(newLine);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I don't have an AddObject method on my Lines Entity? I'm using EF 4.1. Could that be because I am consuming this through a wcf data service?